# Why listing model components in pyTorch is not useful?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, feed-forward

I am trying to create Feed forward neural networks with N layers
So idea is suppose If I want 2 inputs 3 hidden and 2 outputs than I will just pass [2,3,2] to neural network class and neural network model will get created so if I want [100,1000,1000,2]
where in this case 100 is inputs, two hidden layers contains 1000 neuron each and 2 outputs so I want fully connected neural network where I just wanted to pass list which contains number of neuron in each layer. 
So for that I have written following code

```
class FeedforwardNeuralNetModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layers):
        super(FeedforwardNeuralNetModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc=[]
        self.sigmoid=[]
        self.activationValue = []
        self.layers = layers
        for i in range(len(layers)-1):
            self.fc.append(nn.Linear(layers[i],layers[i+1]))
            self.sigmoid.append(nn.Sigmoid())

    def forward(self, x):
        out=x
        for i in range(len(self.fc)):
            out=self.fc[i](out)
            out = self.sigmoid[i](out)
        return out
```

when I tried to use it I found it kind of empty model

```
model=FeedforwardNeuralNetModel([3,5,10,2])

print(model)

>>FeedforwardNeuralNetModel()
```

and when I used following code

```
class FeedforwardNeuralNetModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(FeedforwardNeuralNetModel, self).__init__()
        # Linear function
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim) 
        # Non-linearity
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        # Linear function (readout)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)  

    def forward(self, x):
        # Linear function
        out = self.fc1(x)
        # Non-linearity
        out = self.tanh(out)
        # Linear function (readout)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

and when I tried to print this model I found following result

```
print(model)

>>FeedforwardNeuralNetModel(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=3, out_features=5, bias=True)
(sigmoid): Sigmoid()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=5, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

in my code I am just creating lists that is what difference
I just wanted to understand why in torch listing model components is not useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `print(FeedForwardNetModel([1,2,3])` it gives the following error

`AttributeError: 'FeedforwardNeuralNetModel' object has no attribute '_modules'`

which basically means that the object is not able to recognize modules that you have declared.

---

Why does this happen?

Currently, modules are declared in `self.fc` which is `list` and hence torch has no way of knowing if it is a model unless it does a `deep search` which is bad and inefficient.

---

How can we let torch know that `self.fc` is a list of modules?

By using `nn.ModuleList` (See modified code below). ModuleList and ModuleDict are python list and dictionaries respectively, but they tell torch that the list/dict contains a nn module.

```
#modified init function
def __init__(self, layers): 
    super().__init__()
    self.fc=nn.ModuleList()
    self.sigmoid=[]
    self.activationValue = []
    self.layers = layers
    for i in range(len(layers)-1):
        self.fc.append(nn.Linear(layers[i],layers[i+1]))
        self.sigmoid.append(nn.Sigmoid())
```